# python finding rows with no values

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data from a csv file , i want to find the countries who have not values . I tried this code

```html
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
%matplotlib inline

data= pd.read_csv("EdStatsData.csv", sep=",")
data
```

[image]

```html
gb = data.groupby('Country Code')
explore = gb.count()
explore.describe()
```

[image]

with the function describe i can see i have countries with 0 values .I want to identify which one .
I was thinking the select rows by rows and find if they have 0 values . i dont know how to do  can you help me (a new in python) . thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use any axis=1 to check for least one True per row, then filter with boolean indexing

```
null_data = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```